# Can I attach a vapor barrier directly to plaster, then install cedar tongue & groove?

Tags: plaster, vapor-barrier

I have a 1900 house that's never been insulated, and I'm putting in a new bathroom and kitchen. I plan to blow in cellulose insulation in most of the house walls.

In the bathroom, I have a small space that is 9' above the shower. The ceiling is lath and plaster, but I want to install cedar tongue & groove on top of it. I already put an exhaust fan and recessed light up there. Because it is boxed in by a large beam, I am concerned about moisture build up. I am going to put a vapor barrier in the whole bathroom ceiling. Above the tub is the only space with lath and plaster.

Can I simply staple the vapor barrier to the plaster? Then nail the cedar on top of that? It would be a hassle to remove the lath and plaster just to install a vapor barrier.

Answer (score 0):

That should be fine. In theory the vapor barrier keeps anything behind it below the dew point (depending on weather), so it doesn't much matter what material that is.

**You might just use a sealing paint**, though. This would eliminate the possibility that the existing paint acts as a second vapor barrier, introducing the possibility of moisture being trapped. Otherwise, consider drilling a few holes for ventilation.